# How do I get the file name from a String containing the Absolute file path?

Tags: java, file, filenames, filepath

`String` variable contains a file name, `C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\The File Name.PDF`. How do I only get the file name `The File Name.PDF` as a String?

I planned to split the string, but that is not the optimal solution.

Comment: with reference to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37131215, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

just use **[File.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)**

```
File f = new File("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

using **String methods**:

```
  File f = new File("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");  
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath().substring(f.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
```

Comment: Be careful with pathnames with "/" instead of "\"

Comment: @golimar, this should remove both Windows and Unix path (without using `File` class): `YourStringPath.replaceAll("^.*[\\/\\\\]", "")`

Answer (score 329):

Alternative using [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) (Java 7+):

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
String file = p.getFileName().toString();
```

Note that splitting the string on `\\` is platform dependent as the file separator might vary. `Path#getName` takes care of that issue for you.

Comment: Has anyone done a performance comparison on the various methods in this question?

Comment: @crush I don't think that `Paths.get` accesses the file system so wouldn't expect the performance to be materially different from a substring/indexOf.

Comment: How come it doesn't exist on Android? weird.

Comment: Yes, Path copes with the platform dependent problem of slash/backslash, but only if the file path is from the same machine (or platform). Consider this: you upload file from `Internet Explorer` and it has the path `"C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF"` but your code is working on a Unix/Linux machine then `p.getFileName()` will return the whole path, not just `The File Name.PDF`.

Comment: Calling `toString()` is so awkward.

Answer (score 91):

Using `FilenameUtils` in [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getName(java.lang.String)) :

```
String name1 = FilenameUtils.getName("/ab/cd/xyz.txt");
String name2 = FilenameUtils.getName("c:\\ab\\cd\\xyz.txt");
```

Comment: I think this one may be the best, because sometimes you may have to process the file path from other platform

Comment: Btw anyone wants to get the filename minus extension can use `FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filePath)`

Comment: This is the best solution. It is platform independent.

Answer (score 36):

Considering the `String` you're asking about is

```
C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\The File Name.PDF
```

we need to extract everything after the last separator, ie. `\`. That is what we are interested in.

You can do

```
String fullPath = "C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF";
int index = fullPath.lastIndexOf("\\");
String fileName = fullPath.substring(index + 1);
```

This will retrieve the index of the last `\` in your `String` and extract everything that comes after it into `fileName`.

*If you have a `String` with a different separator, adjust the `lastIndexOf` to use that separator.* (There's even an [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-) that accepts an entire `String` as a separator.)

I've omitted it in the example above, but if you're unsure where the `String` comes from or what it might contain, you'll want to validate that the `lastIndexOf` returns a non-negative value because the [Javadoc states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-) it'll return

> -1 if there is no such occurrence

Comment: Actually -1  return value can be used. 
Assuming the path is not empty and relative path are possible,  If '\\' is not found then index +1 is 0 which is the position of the file name in that case.

Answer (score 31):

Since 1.7

```
    Path p = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\1.txt");
    String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
    String directory = p.getParent().toString();
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use path = C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\TheFileName.PDF

```
String strPath = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, path.length());
```

Comment: You should use \\ instead of \

Comment: You should not use any of those as it is platform dependent. `/` on unix and `\\`(AND THERE IS A BUG IN THE MARKDOWN PARSER HERE) on windows. You can't know. Use another solution like `File` or `Paths`.

Comment: Is `File.separator` also platform dependent?  Or would this work...

`String strPath = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1, path.length());`

Comment: File.separator & File.separatorChar are both "/" on UNIX/Linux/macOS version of JDK, and both "\" on Windows version.

Comment: `File.separator` won't always work here because in Windows a filename can be separated by either `"/"` or `"\\"`.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers didn't quite work for my specific scenario, where I am reading paths that have originated from an OS different to my current one. To elaborate I am saving email attachments saved from a Windows platform on a Linux server. The filename returned from the JavaMail API is something like 'C:\temp\hello.xls'

The solution I ended up with:

```
String filenameWithPath = "C:\\temp\\hello.xls";
String[] tokens = filenameWithPath.split("[\\\\|/]");
String filename = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 4):

getFileName() method of java.nio.file.Path used to return the name of the file or directory pointed by this path object.

Path getFileName()

For reference:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/path-getfilename-method-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 3):

Considere the case that Java is Multiplatform:

```
int lastPath = fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
if (lastPath!=-1){
    fileName = fileName.substring(lastPath+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A method without any dependency and takes care of **..** , **.** and duplicate separators.

```
public static String getFileName(String filePath) {
    if( filePath==null || filePath.length()==0 )
        return "";
    filePath = filePath.replaceAll("[/\\\\]+", "/");
    int len = filePath.length(),
        upCount = 0;
    while( len>0 ) {
        //remove trailing separator
        if( filePath.charAt(len-1)=='/' ) {
            len--;
            if( len==0 )
                return "";
        }
        int lastInd = filePath.lastIndexOf('/', len-1);
        String fileName = filePath.substring(lastInd+1, len);
        if( fileName.equals(".") ) {
            len--;
        }
        else if( fileName.equals("..") ) {
            len -= 2;
            upCount++;
        }
        else {
            if( upCount==0 )
                return fileName;
            upCount--;
            len -= fileName.length();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Test case:

```
@Test
public void testGetFileName() {
    assertEquals("", getFileName("/"));
    assertEquals("", getFileName("////"));
    assertEquals("", getFileName("//C//.//../"));
    assertEquals("", getFileName("C//.//../"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("C"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("/C"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("/C/"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("//C//"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("/A/B/C/"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("/A/B/C"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("/C/./B/../"));
    assertEquals("C", getFileName("//C//./B//..///"));
    assertEquals("user", getFileName("/user/java/.."));
    assertEquals("C:", getFileName("C:"));
    assertEquals("C:", getFileName("/C:"));
    assertEquals("java", getFileName("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\java\\bin\\.."));
    assertEquals("C.ext", getFileName("/A/B/C.ext"));
    assertEquals("C.ext", getFileName("C.ext"));
}
```

Maybe getFileName is a bit confusing, because it returns directory names also. It returns the name of file or last directory in a path.

Answer (score 0):

extract file name using java regex *.

```
public String extractFileName(String fullPathFile){
        try {
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([^\\\\/:*?\"<>|\r\n]+$)");
            Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(fullPathFile);
            if (regexMatcher.find()){
                return regexMatcher.group(1);
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
            LOG.info("extractFileName::pattern problem <"+fullPathFile+">",ex);
        }
        return fullPathFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileInfo object to get all information of your file.

```
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\The File Name.PDF");
    MessageBox.Show(f.Name);
    MessageBox.Show(f.FullName);
    MessageBox.Show(f.Extension );
    MessageBox.Show(f.DirectoryName);
```

Answer (score -6):

This answer works for me in c#:

```
using System.IO;
string fileName = Path.GetFileName("C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\The File Name.PDF");
```

Comment: question is for java.