# How to split the string a android?

Tags: java

I am working on android application. I am getting the image from gallery. Also I am getting the image path from gallery. Now my requirement is I want to get only the image name with the extension . How can I do that? Please help me.

```
String imgpath =  "/mnt/sdcard/joke.png";
```

The image extension can be anything `joke.png` or `joke.jpeg`. I need to get the image name with extension finally.

i.e I want to split the above string and get only `joke.png`.

How can I achieve that? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: have you tried `imgpath.split("/");`?

Comment: Try to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string
here many different ways for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String imgpath = "/mnt/sdcard/joke.png";

String result = imgpath.substring(imgpath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); 
System.out.println("Image name " + result);
```

Output :-

```
Image name joke.png
```

You should read [How do I get the file name from a String containing the Absolute file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526260/how-do-i-get-the-file-name-from-a-string-containing-the-absolute-file-path)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in Android like in any Java program:

```
String[] parts = imagepath.split("/");
String result = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String s[] = imgpath.split("/");
String result = s[s.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String imgName = imgpath.substring((imgpath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), imgpath.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with Regex too, if that is the hammer you have in your hands:

```
String fileName = null;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|.*/)([^/]*)$");
Matcher m = pattern.getMatcher(filenameWithPath);
if(matcher.matches()) {

        fileName = matcher.group(2);
}
```

**But don't be tempted to do this.** This is less readable, and probably even slower than the other methods.