# JSch put file into a subdirectory

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am trying to place a file into SFTP directory using JSch.

```
channelSftp.cd(destDir);
channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(filePath), filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar)));
```

But the above code is placing the file always in the SFTP user home directory instead of `destDir`. For example, if I create a subdirectory `test` under user home directory and set `destDir` as `channelSftp.getHome()+"test"`, still the file is being copies to user home directory only instead of test sub-directory.

I tried to list files in `destDir` (`test` sub-directory), it is showing all files/directories under `test` directory.

```
Vector<com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry> vv = channelSftp.ls(destDir);
if(vv != null) {
     for(int ii=0; ii<vv.size(); ii++){
         Object obj=vv.elementAt(ii);
         if(obj instanceof LsEntry){
             System.out.println(((LsEntry)obj).getLongname());
         }
     }
 }
```

Any suggestions? I looked at permissions (`test` sub-directory has exactly same permissions as SFTP user home directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar))` result includes even the last separator.

So if you pass `/home/user/file.txt`, you get `/file.txt`. That is an absolute path, so any working directory is disregarded and you effectively always write to a root folder.

You want `filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar) + 1)` to get only `file.txt`.

See also [How do I get the file name from a String containing the Absolute file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14526260/850848)

Answer (score 0):

This works for very well !!

```
       channel.connect();

       try {
          channel.mkdir("subdir");
       } catch (Exception e) {
          // ... do something if subdir already exists
       }

       // Then the trick !
       channel.put(inputStream, "subdir" + "/" + "filename.ext");
```