# Quit text from string that references a path JAVA

Tags: java, string, path

If i have a String that contains a path like

> "D:\Folder\Folder2\file.txt"

, how can i remove the file and have only

> "D:\Folder\Folder2"

Thank you for your time. :D

Comment: Hint: You can use String's `substring` and `lastIndexOf` methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the file name from a String containing the Absolute file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526260/how-do-i-get-the-file-name-from-a-string-containing-the-absolute-file-path)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String a = "D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\file.txt";
System.out.print(a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf("\\")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Apaches FilenameUtils..

```
 This class defines six components within a filename (example
 C:\dev\project\file.txt):
 
 the prefix - C:\ 
 the path - dev\project\ 
 the full path -> C:\dev\project\ 
 the name - file.txt 
 the base name - file 
 the extension - txt
```

So by using following code, you get the full path (without the filename):

```
getFullPath("D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\file.txt");
```

Please have a look at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Java IO and NIO packages has classes for file handling - `File` and `Path`. All of these do same job to extract parent as Path, File or String and avoid hardcoding file separator:

**import java.io.File**:

```
 File parent   = new File("D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\file.txt").getParentFile();
 String parent = new File("D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\file.txt").getParent();
```

**import java.nio.file.Path**:

```
 Path parent   = Path.of("D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\file.txt").getParent();
 String parent = Path.of("D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\file.txt").getParent().toString();
```