# Add JAR files in Selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have added JAR files, but I am still getting this error:

> ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2a3b.png)

Comment: A description, etc. ought to be included as well. Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74177719/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set thee chromedriver path on the system as a variable, either manually or through code.

You don't need the JAR files on the project.

Please look at [my reply on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306379/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-b/72306657#72306657).

I can’t repeat answers, but it's the same situation.